# If parent div has 4 of more divs inside of it, then display scroll arrow containers

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I have a `parent div` which containers a list of `divs`.

If there are 4 or more `child divs` inside of this `parent div` then I would like to display the scroll arrow containers.

If there is less, then display none.

Markup is like this:

```
<div class="associated-product__swatches associated-images">
    <div class="associated-images__scroll scroll-up disabled">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden-xs associated-images__container product-alternate">
        <a href="#" class="not-no-image" title="S, Crystal" data-price="£209.95" data-saleprice="£104.98" data-colourid="2142" data-colourtitle="S, Crystal" data-productid="203142">
            <span data-hires="#">
                <img src="#" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden-xs associated-images__container product-alternate">
        <a href="#" class="not-no-image" title="S, Crystal" data-price="£209.95" data-saleprice="£104.98" data-colourid="2142" data-colourtitle="S, Crystal" data-productid="203142">
            <span data-hires="#">
                <img src="#" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden-xs associated-images__container product-alternate">
        <a href="#" class="not-no-image" title="S, Crystal" data-price="£209.95" data-saleprice="£104.98" data-colourid="2142" data-colourtitle="S, Crystal" data-productid="203142">
            <span data-hires="#">
                <img src="#" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden-xs associated-images__container product-alternate">
        <a href="#" class="not-no-image" title="S, Crystal" data-price="£209.95" data-saleprice="£104.98" data-colourid="2142" data-colourtitle="S, Crystal" data-productid="203142">
            <span data-hires="#">
                <img src="#" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="associated-images__scroll scroll-down">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any assistance or suggestions would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is expected you at least make an attempt to resolve the problem  yourself and then if you are stuck with a particular piece of your code, ask a question here.  In it's current form, your question is off topic for SO

Comment: $('.associated-images__scroller div').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.find('div').length >= 4) { //if looking for direct descendants then do .children('div').length
      $this.find('associated-images__scroll').addClass('show');
  } else {
$('associated-images__scroll').hide();
  }
});

Comment: tried using the above - but seems to remove all scroll arrow containers

Comment: you might want to add jquery as a tag - you will get more responses.  Also edit your question and add the code to it rather than putting it in a comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to solve this. In your javascript code you need to get a reference to the parent div element and the scroll container element. You can do this using the 'document' object like this:

```
var parentDiv = document.getElementById("giveYourDivAnIdAndReferenceItHere")
var scrollArrowContainer = document.getElementById("doTheSameForThisOne")
```

Once you have that reference, you can parse its 'children' property.

```
if(parentDiv.children > 4) {...}
```

And now you can do conditional logic to add or remove a class from your scroll container:

```
scrollArrowContainer.classList.add('classThatHidesElement')
scrollArrowContainer.classList.remove('classThatHidesElement')
```

A better approach than checking the number of children would be to compare the screen height and your parent div's height, and scroll based on that instead

Answer (score 0):

Use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) :

```
.associated-images__scroll {
    display: none;
}

div.associated-images__container:nth-child(4) ~ .associated-images__scroll {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: nice! If that works it is cleaner than my solution, should OP insist on doing the conditional against the number of children

Comment: This solution heavily assumes that there will not be any other child elements on top of the targetted divs. If there are then the `last-child` can go wrong.